# PHP error reporting

Tags: joomla-3.x, error-handling, error-reporting, fatal-error

I'm trying to create a behaviour such as : if there's a php fatal error, I want the joomla error page to show up, but I also want to receive a mail telling me what the error was.

The idea here is to get rid off the step to check in apache's error log to find out the specific error. I also want my visitor to see the custom error page I've set up.

I've seen a few things that might help me, like "ErrorDocument 500 /myerrorpage" however, I can't see a way to catch the error there.

Is there a way to send a mail containing the error ? The only solution I can see right now is sending a mail like "Hey, someone just landed on the error page, you might want to check out apache's error log to fix it".

PS : If possible I'd like not to use a third party module or plugin, I prefer making my one in terms of security/maintainability

Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to create a custom PHP error handler and have that send you an email.

You can use **FILE** and **FUNCTION** and **LINE** constants to load where the error happened into the email that you alert yourself with.

Take a look at how to do all of that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error

Answer (score 4):

I've found out that the easiest/faster method to resolve this was to use a script reading apache's logs and send a mail every day with a summary.

FYI : Server's setup has a daily log rotation, run the script through crontab, just before rotation time.
(Plus : I'm french, so there are french words in the mail being sent).

Here's the script : (I know it could be improved, but it still does the needed work)

```
<?php

$start = microtime(true);
$filepath = "PATH/TO/APACHE/LOGS";
$filename = "error.log";
$to = "MAILTO@ME.COM";

$file = file($filepath . $filename);

$warnings = [];
$errors = [];
$notices = [];

foreach($file as $line) {
    $error = strpos($line, "PHP Fatal error");
    if ($error !== false) {
        $exp = explode("PHP Fatal error", $line);
        $exp2 = explode(", referer", $exp[1]);
        $final = "PHP Fatal error" . $exp2[0];
        isset($errors[$final]) ? $errors[$final]+= 1 : $errors[$final]= 1;
    } else {
        $warning = strpos($line, "PHP Warning");
        if ($warning !== false) {
            $exp = explode("PHP Warning", $line);
            $exp2 = explode(", referer", $exp[1]);
            $final = "PHP Warning" . $exp2[0];
            isset($warnings[$final]) ? $warnings[$final]+= 1 : $warnings[$final]= 1;
        } else {
            $notice = strpos($line, "PHP Notice");
            if ($notice !== false) {
                $exp = explode("PHP Notice", $line);
                $exp2 = explode(", referer", $exp[1]);
                $final = "PHP Notice" . $exp2[0];
                isset($notices[$final]) ? $notices[$final]+= 1 : $notices[$final]= 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

$errorNb = countArray($errors);
$warningNb = countArray($warnings);
$noticeNb = countArray($notices);

function countArray($ar) {
    $nb = 0; foreach($ar as $a){ $nb+=$a; } return $nb;
}

$subject = "Rapport apache : Erreurs : " . $errorNb . " - Warnings : " . $warningNb . " - Notices :" .$noticeNb;
$message = "<br>Liste des erreurs (PHP Fatal error) rencontrées :"."<br>";
foreach($errors as $i => $e) {
    $message .= "Rencontré " . $e . " fois : " . $i . "<br>";
}
$message .= "<br>"."<br>Liste des warning (PHP Warning) rencontrées :"."<br>";
foreach($warnings as $i => $e) {
    $message .= "Rencontré " . $e . " fois : " . $i . "<br>";
}
$message .= "<br>"."<br>Liste des erreurs (PHP Notice) rencontrées :"."<br>";
foreach($notices as $i => $e) {
    $message .= "Rencontré " . $e . " fois : " . $i . "<br>";
}

//echo $subject . "<br>" . "<br>";

$message.= "<br><br><br><br>Rapport généré en " . (microtime(true) - $start) . " secondes";

//echo $message;

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Maybe you want to add lines to delete error.log after the system has sent  the email?

Comment: As I said, logs are rotated every day and stored in .gz so that you still have access to them. The server handles that, the script is only for reading + reporting purpose

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't read that. Anyway, would it be possible to have the script as an installable plugin? We have public [JSE repo](https://github.com/Joomla-StackExchange) on github for any installable plugins/modules we're written